# Why does $(XZ\otimes I)|\Phi^+\rangle$ equal the Bell state $|\Psi^-\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-state, experimental-realization, bell-basis

I'm slightly confused by the solution provided below by a suggested solution online to convert |$\phi^+$⟩ to |$\psi^-$⟩.

I tried doing the operation XZ but I got $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$(|10⟩-|01⟩) instead of |$\psi^-$⟩.

However, applying ZX seems to provide me with the right answer.

Would appreciate the verification!

$$
\begin{align}
(XZ \otimes I) |\Phi^+\rangle &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(XZ|0\rangle \otimes I |0\rangle + XZ |1\rangle \otimes |1\rangle) \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(X|0\rangle \otimes I|0\rangle - X|1\rangle \otimes I |1\rangle) \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|1\rangle \otimes |0\rangle - |0\rangle \otimes |1\rangle) \\
&= |\Psi^-\rangle
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Note that $XZ$ is $ZX$, up to a phase factor. Since global (!) phase factors are unobservable in quantum mechanics, applying either $ZX$ or $XZ$ will lead to the same physical outcome.

Comment: please use latex to format equations

Comment: @glS shouldn't it be `{\sqrt{2}` in the 2nd last step?

Comment: @VanPeer yes, but it shouldn't be a screenshot in the first place. The same edit with latex would have been fine

Comment: @KennethGoodenough I see! Could you please explain how does this phase factor concept work here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Kenneth comment is right.

Note that:

$$ XZ |\Phi^+\rangle = XZ\bigg(\dfrac{|00\rangle + |11\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} \bigg) = \dfrac{|10\rangle - |01\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} = - \bigg( \dfrac{|01\rangle - |10\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} \bigg) = -|\Psi^-\rangle $$

But there is no distinction between the state $-|\Psi^-\rangle $ and $|\Psi^-\rangle $ quantum mechanically. That is, they are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks! How can we prove that these two states are not distinguishable quantum mechanically?

Comment: @Colin Hong In term of why overall phase doesn't matter, check out this answer here: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/9630/9858